# Presto Sound Library

Tags: android, media-player

I'm trying to speed up playback of podcasts on android using Presto library. it crashes when I instantiate it with "useService" set to true. works fine if I don't use Service, but then I don't get to set the playback speed.
Any helps, pointers or alternatives to Presto appreciated. my media playback object is designed to be swappable, so if there is anything else out there, I can switch easily.

Comment: Did you manage to make this library working ? Thanks.